# How to choose the MOSFETs for BLDC motor drive?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

How to select the proper MOSFETs for Brushless DC motor drive circuit?

The Motor will work at 22.2V max. voltage and 40A max. current.

Comment: Have you tried looking at a MOSFET data sheet and seeing what sense you can make of it in view of the voltage and current values presented in your question?

Comment: @Andyaka I am asking if there are any factors than voltage and current.

Comment: Other factors: on-resistance, gate-capacitance, switching speed, reverse recovery speed of the MOSFET parasitic diode, drain-source capacitance, gate threshold voltage...

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with MOSFETs that are capable of 2 x current you need and 2 x voltage you need. There will be spikes of current and voltage that must be handled.
Otherwise, the most important thing is ON resistance, gate capacitance and gate threshold voltage.